# Correr Angular en AWS y ligar a un dominio

Tags: nodejs, aws, angular-cli

Estoy intentando levantar una instancia en AWS con Angular pero no he podido.

- He creado mi instancia en EC2, con sus respectivos grupos y reglas de enrutamiento (incluidos los puertos 22, 80, 443 y 4200)
- He creado mi elasticIP
- Con mis Key Pair he entrado al SSH por Putty
- He instalado node ( 10.x )
- He instalado npm ( 6.x )
- He instalado angularCLI ( 7.x )
- Corri la siguiente instrucción `ng new myapp`
- Puse `ng build`
- Luego `ng serve`

Esto de menos me tendría que mostrar el tutorial básico que tiene por default Angular, me dice que correrá en el localhost:4200 por lo que se me hace raro
He ingresado a la IP que me dió la elasticIP pero dice La conexión ha sido rechazada, si añado el puerto 4200 dice que tardó en contestar.
¿Alguien Me puede decir que se me está escapando?

De igual forma intenté hacerlo vía Elastic Beanstalk... corrió la instancia, pero no crea las Key Pair entonces no puedo entrar al servidor que creó.

he visto este [Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX82eeuCPIg) para guiarme, pero al final construye el servidor por medio de la instrucción `node` y al parecer ejecuta un archivo hecho con el framework express, por lo que estoy un poco perdido.

Hice otra instancia con la misma configuración de EC2 pero esta vez solo instalé `nginx` y funcionó correctamente por lo que descartaría un problema de reglas de enrutamiento. Algo estoy haciendo mal al hechar a andar la aplicación ya sea con angular o con node ( Que al final angular se sirve de una forma peculiar de node )

Terminando este paso el siguiente es ligar la instancia a un dominio ya comprado, con lo cual me estoy guiando con este [Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xce0X0pGL98)

Agrecedería un tutorial de guía, si alguien tiene alguno.

Comment: Ya intentaste utilizar `curl localhost:4200` o `netstat -tlpn | grep 4200` dentro de tu instancia para ver si está corriendo tu servicio?

Comment: Gracias, ya actualicé mi pregunta y añadí un par de cosas que intenté.

Comment: tiene que hacer el `ng build` mover la carpeta `dist` a `/var/www/` y para acceder algo como `http://tu_ip/dist`

Answer (score 1):

No sé casi nada de Angular pero escribe

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

para correr tu aplicación.
Supuse que era algo por el estilo debido a que cuando hacía un

```
netstat -tlpn
```

lanzaba un:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12745/ng serve
```

Y el hecho de que tenga como host el 127.0.0.1 sólo lo hace visible para el localhost. En cambio, si le pones el host como el 0.0.0.0 hace que pueda ser visible desde todas las direcciones ipv4 disponibles.

Después de lanzar el nuevo comando ng serve, puedes revisar con netstat y te devolverá algo como

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12745/ng serve --ho
```

Y ya puedes acceder desde tu navegador con http://<tu_ip>:4200

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto lo hice en una instancia de free tier de AWS, instalé lo necesario con `yum` y `npm`

Y para añadir un nombre de dominio, AWS parece que tiene su propio tutorial.

https://aws.amazon.com/es/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/

### Actualización 1

Respecto a lo que comentaba @JackNavaRow, recuerda que `ng serve` es para pruebas, entonces no tendría mucho "sentido" (más que para fines de aprendizaje) el ponerlo a correr de forma pública, es decir, permitir que cualquier individuo con acceso a esa ip pueda verlo. Eso lo podrías hacer de forma local, incluso con un port forwarding.

```
ssh -L 4200:127.0.0.1:4200 instancia_de_aws
```

Luego correr el `ng serve` y en tu explorador personal acceder a la dirección "127.0.0.1:4200".

De todas maneras esto sería sólo para casos específicos de prueba.

Comment: Ya están las reglas de enrutamiento, tanto http como https

Comment: Ya usaste `nmap -T4 -A ip_de_instancia` para ver si se muestran como abiertos esos puertos?

Comment: Oye, pero las reglas de firewall si permiten ingreso de tráfico al puerto 4200 en el que mencionaste que estaba corriendo tu app de angular? Creo que algo de esa info está aquí. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: Creo que sería algo así (insisto en no saber mucho de AWS :( ) https://imgur.com/a/k5omV41

Comment: Gracias, ya actualicé mi pregunta y añadí un par de cosas que intenté.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, espera que actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: @mrc_es ese es el modo "develop" de angular , lo ideal es que se publique se ejecute `ng build ` en el proyecto mover la carpeta `dist` a `/var/www/` y luego acceder a algo como `http://<tu_ip>/dist`, claro se puede modificar el virtualhost pero para no hacer la respuesta larga

Comment: Toda la razón. De hecho se me hizo raro que quisiera tener visible públicamente un *hello world* de un webserver de pruebas de angular.

Comment: Ya tengo el código en GIT, pero de nada me sirve estarlo clonando si nisiquiera puedo levantar el servicio.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Al menos yo voy a intentar lo que sugeriste. Para probar algo nuevo :)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Tienes toda la razón.
https://imgur.com/a/fpi3SU4
Cabe destacar que esto lo hice con nginx y no con apache, pero ese será otro tema.

Answer (score 0):

Como primer paso verificaría la conexión a este puerto desde el exterior por medio de telnet

```
telnet <ip> <port>
```

En caso de estar cerrado verificaría que la página web esté allí, conectado al host por medio de ssh, usuaría el comando curl para ello

```
curl localhost:4200
```

En caso de haber mostrado el código HTML haría la última verificación. Mediante el comando netstat observo que el servicio se encuentre escuchando todas las peticiones mediante la dirección no especificada 0.0.0.0

```
netstat -tlpn | grep 4200
```

Para el caso de que todas las verificaciones sean positivas concluiría que el problema es de configuración del servidor. Aquí solo podría dar ideas ya que desconozco la distribución linux empleada. El paso a seguir sería permitir la conexión a este puerto ya que el firewall podría no permitirlo, recuerde que el puerto 4200 no es el idóneo para ésto, yo aconsejo instalar un servidor web como NGINX para así enrutar las conexiones que lleguen del puerto 80. En caso de estar usando Ubuntu y desee habilitar el puerto 4200 puede emplear el comando ufw

```
sudo ufw allow 4200/tcp
```

Adicionalmente supongo que si está usando AWS es porque se desea desplegar en producción por lo que yo no recomendaría instalar todo angular y sus librerías para luego usar el comando `ng serve`, para esto constuiría la solución por medio del comando `ng build -prod` y por último recuerde que puede cambiar el puerto 4200 usando `ng serve --port <port>`

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero como tal, no está corriendo en localhost, es una instancia de amazon que obviamente no es localhost, por lo que entiendo Node vendría a suplantar a Nginx, me considero novato en este tema, la versión del servidor es Ubuntu 18

Comment: Angular y Node son completamente diferentes. Es cierto que se puede obtener mediante Express.js un servicio web completamente funcional sin embargo no reemplaza a NGINX ya que éste último sirve en este caso como enrutador o proxy reverso (suponga que tiene muchas páginas web hechas en node, necesita de alguien que diga a cuál ir cuando abran dominio.com). Para el caso de angular hay que generar un compilado que resulta en un HTML, varios .js y un css donde con ayuda de NGINX usted desplegará, ng serve no es usado para producción.

Answer (score -1):

El **ng serve** solo sirve como servidor local (provisional) para desarrollo

Tu proyecto de Angular funciona como una Aplicación Web, y puedes montarla en cualquier servidor Web (Apache, NGINX) que tengas dentro de tu instancia EC2, solo ocupas compilar el proyecto:

```
ng build
```

[Angular build](https://angular.io/cli/build)

[Angular deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Una vez que tengas el build del proyecto se generara una carpeta llamada "**dist**" que contendrá la raíz de tu proyecto:

[image]
[image]

Solo restaría configurar en tu servidor Web el proyecto compilado, como un nuevo sitio. (Puedes copiar y pegar el contenido de la carpeta **dist** dentro de la raíz de tu Apache o NGINX).

Por ultimo solo vincula la IP elástica a la instancia que estés utilizando:

**Desde la consola de AWS entramos a Elastic IPs**
[image: AWS Console]
**Elegimos la IP que queremos asociar**
[image: Elastic IP Panel]
**Seleccionamos la instancia a la que le vamos a asociar la IP**
[image]

Comment: El OP se refiere específicamente a montar un instancia de Angular en AWS, no a algún otro tipo de contenedor

Comment: Ya creo la instancia en AWS, todo lo esta haciendo bien, solo respondí lo que complementaba su trabajo, ya que es la forma correcta de hacer un deploy de Angular, si el OP considera que no es de utilidad se borra y listo.